# Nuxtjs doesn't fetch data on page refresh

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I'm working on dev everything works fine, but when I build using nuxt generate I have an issue on the server side.

Everytime I refresh a page it will add a slash at the end of the url :

```
https://mywebsite.com/page
```

Will become

```
https://mywebsite.com/page/
```

I'm working on a headless CMS using Wordpress, whenever I arrive on this new url the page will be generated with the content I had when I built the project, I don't really know how to explain this any better so here's an example :
Let's say I updated my page at 10am with the following content

```
Hello it's 10am
```

Then I would build my project at 10:05am and upload it on the server.
If I go back to Wordpress and update my page at 10:30am and change its content to :

```
Hello it is now 10:30am
```

If i go to **https://mywebsite.com/page** I will get the content from 10:30am but if I refresh it and go to **https://mywebsite.com/page/** I will get the content from 10am

I tried setting the trailingSlash to false in my nuxt.config.js but it didn't work and I still go to the url with a slash at the end whenever I refresh a page

```
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
}
```

Edit : Here's how I fetch data on _slug.vue (used for article pages) for example

```
    export default {

  async asyncData ({params}) {
    const post = await fetch(Config.wpDomain + Config.api.Articles + `?slug=${params.slug}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())

    return {
      title : post[0].title.rendered,
      categories : post[0].categories,
      region : post[0].acf.region_de.post_title,
      content : post[0].content.rendered
    }
  },

}
```

The URL I give to my fetch works fine since I retrieve the right content on dev and on first page load, but when refreshing the returned data will be the one that was saved when I built my app like I explained above

Comment: How do you fetch the data? Where is your app hosted?

Comment: I will update my question to add the fetching process, the site is hosted on our OVH server

Comment: Maybe there is so cache issue or some over-writting by the server. You are supposed to have the exact same content. Try to maybe host it on Netlify and see if the cache is still annoying there. Never experienced this kind of bug myself. I do use the default (`trailingSlash: true`). This is probably also coming from the way that you do generate your pages, do you have some custom things in `generate` in your `nuxt.config.js` or do you use the default directories routing of Nuxt?

Comment: In my routes property I only have something similar to this https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-which-returns-a-promise I tried to remove it, didn't solve my problem